# Socket.io disconnects when refreshed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to build a live chat, I am using mongodb and socket.io to store the messages and users.

When a new user is created that user is stored in the mongodb and in the socket object.

If a user refreshes the page the user is removed from the socket object, meaning now in order for that person to get back in they have to create a new username and that generates a new socket.

Here is what my server side code looks like

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Live socket communication with front end:
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|
*/

var users = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Listen to a new user then emit the user to all clients
    socket.on('new user', function (data) {

        // Check mongodb to see if the user exists and emit proper message
        models.Message.findOne({username:data},function(err,user){
            if(err){
                console.log('something went wrong')
            }
            else if(user){
                socket.emit('username taken', 'something');
            }
            else{
                socket.emit('create user', data);
                socket.userName = data;
                socket.connected = true;
                users[socket.userName] = socket;
                io.sockets.emit('user name', Object.keys(users));
            }
        });

    });

    socket.on('facebook id', function(data) {

        models.User.findOne({username:data.name}, function(err, user) {
            if (user) {
                console.log('User already exists');
                socket.userName = data.name;
                socket.facebook_id = data.id;
                socket.connected = true;
                users[socket.userName] = socket;
                io.sockets.emit('user name', Object.keys(users));
            } 
            else {
                var newUser = new models.User({
                    username: data.name,
                    facebook_id: data.id
                });
                newUser.save(function(err, user) {
                    console.log('successfully inserted user/user: ' + user._id);
                });
            }
        });

    });

    // Listen to a new message then emit the message to all clients
    socket.on('send message', function (data, callback) {

        io.sockets.emit('new message', {message: data, username: socket.userName, facebook_id: socket.facebook_id});

    });

    // Logic when client disconnects
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {

        if(!socket.userName) return;
        seeder.disconnect(socket.userName);
        delete users[socket.userName]
        io.sockets.emit('user disconnected', Object.keys(users));

    });

});
```

You see in my disconnect I remove the socket from the users object.

My question would be is there a way to save the socket info on disconnect then if the same socket tries to connect have it recognize the user and continue?

**Additonal:** I am thinking maybe I need to focus on creating a user login with mongodb first, then using that log in session data and pass that to the socket, creating a socket object with current database details? Does that sound like something that makes more sense, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cookies to identify users. Generate a random hash, put it in cookies, and thus this data will be transferred when establishing connection between client and server.

The client code may look like:

```
function generateHash(len) {
  var symbols = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
  var hash = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var symIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length);
    hash += symbols.charAt(symIndex);
  }
  return hash;
}
if (!/\buser_id=/.test(document.cookie)) { //if no 'user_id' in cookies
  document.cookie = 'user_id=' + generateHash(32);  //add cookie 'user_id'
}

//here goes establishing connection to server via `io.connect`
```

On the server-side you can write:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var cookie = socket.handshake.headers.cookie;
  var match = cookie.match(/\buser_id=([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})/);  //parse cookie header
  var userId = match ? match[1] : null;
  //...
```

Thus you have `userId` variable which is unique for each user. Then you can comment this line:

```
delete users[socket.userName]
```

because you should keep the user data.

You may now store your `users` object with `userId` (not username) as a key, and on each connection check whether `users[userId] != null`. And if such user exists, use their socket info

Comment: I actually found this tutorial http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local I am going to try and merge sockets with what I learned here. The above definitely helps grasp how I can leverage cookies.